# Use JSON Schema to check unique properties

Tags: json, validation, json.net

I have the JSON with the structure

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
              "field1": "*",
              "field2": "*"
        },
        "property2": {
              "field3": "*",
              "filed5": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `properties` can have different items (like property1, property2...)

I generated a JSON Schema for this sturcture

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Items": {
      "id": "Items",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "id": "0",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "properties": {
            "id": "properties",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "property1": {
                "id": "property1",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "field1": {
                    "id": "field1",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "field2": {
                    "id": "field2",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "property2": {
                "id": "property2",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "field3": {
                    "id": "field3",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "filed5": {
                    "id": "filed5",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "additionalItems": false
    }
  }
}
```

But when I check the JSON with two properties with the same name (property1 in the JSON below), it doesn't notify, that the properties should be unique.

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
              "field1": "*",
              "field2": "*"
        },
        "property1": {
              "field1": "*",
              "field2": "*"
        },
        "property2": {
              "field3": "*",
              "filed5": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to solve this ?